# Misplaced text when using APA

Tags: pdftex, apa6, sharelatex

In my document, a couple of lines from one section are placed after the first couple of lines of the next section.

This document reproduces the error:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{University}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\foreach \i in {1,...,30}{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa }

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb }

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc }

\section{Method}

\subsection{Materials}
\foreach \i in {1,...,8}{dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd }
\end{document}
```

[image: Misplaced paragraphs]

Notice that the b and c paragraphs are placed after the Materials heading, even though they come before in the source.

It seems to be highly dependent on the spacing. Adding a couple of lines seems to fix the issues, but I'd rather not have to change my text just because of this error. If it's relevant, I'm using sharelatex with pdflatex.

Why does this happen? Can I do anything to fix this (without changing the text itself)?

---

Here is another example of the issues, using short words instead of long pseudowords, and occurring on the second page of the document.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{University}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\foreach \i in {1,...,136}{aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa }

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}{bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb }

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}{ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc ccc }

\section{Method}
\subsection{Materials}
\foreach \i in {1,...,8}{ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd ddd }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You've really chosen an awkward example, together with a fixed-width font. You can fix this (to answer your question) by using regular text in the regular (journal-suggested) text font (therefore, by removing `\tt` or `\ttfamily`).

Comment: The `\tt` doesn't seem to affect the issue. It was added to make the text monospace for convenience.

Removing the `\tt` and adding additional `c`s causes the same issues.

Comment: If I remove your "convenient" `\tt` (or `\ttfamily`), the sectional titles display in the appropriate order. Also, the mis-alignment with the text running into the margins are because of the fact that you're using non-words for which TeX can't find appropriate hyphenations. That's why I call this an "awkward example".

Comment: It seems that `apa.cls` has a hard time when the document doesn't fill up the first page.

Comment: @Werner I don't mean to be contrarian, but this problem came up when writing a paper in a normal font with real words. I don't see how hyphenation is relevant to text placement. I've edited the question to remove the `\tt`.

Answer (score 2):

The example is not significant, sorry. The `apa` class loads `flushend` that should balance the columns in the last page; however, if the document doesn't fill the first page, the package conflicts with the placement of the author information at the bottom of the left column in the first page.

Just add some text in order to fill up the first page and the problem disappears.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{University}
\abstract{Text of your abstract...}
\acknowledgements{Author notes, acknowledgements, contact information...}
\rightheader{Running head for journal look}
\shorttitle{Short title for manuscript header}
\leftheader{Left head for journal look}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Upon changing `\lipsum[1-5]` into `\lipsum[1-20]` the first page is typeset correctly.

If you need a one page document, issue `\raggedend` after `\maketitle`.

Comment: I'm not sure what notion of "significance" you had in mind. `\lipsum` makes for bad filler text here, since the issue seems to be affected by the precise number of lines of text.

It looks like `flushend` behaves badly even for multi-page documents. I'm able to reproduce this problem on the second page by changing the first foreach in my example to `\foreach \i in {1,...,135}{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\par}`.

The `\raggedend` does seem to fix this though.

Comment: @Michaelll Try using `aaa aaa aaa aaa` and so on, instead of those long pseudowords. You'll see that in the case you fill up at least the first page the problem disappears.

Comment: The same issue occurs with short words. See my latest edit.

Comment: @Michaelll The `\par` used in `\foreach` is suspicious. Please, give a real world example; in any case, this seems a bug in `flushend`,

Comment: I don't post on StackExchange often, but isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) preferred? The `\par` usage was an artifact from an older version that was still using pseudowords (the columns began to overflow). I've edited my question to remove the `\par`s.